# Не выводится сообщение об ошибке

Tags: php

```
<?php
    require 'db.php';
    $data = $_Post;
    if ( isset($data['do_signup']) )
    {
        //здесь регистрируем
        $errors = array();
        if( trim($data['nickname']) == '')
        {
            $errors[] = 'Введите имя вашего персонажа';
        }
        if( trim($data['email']) == '')
        {
            $errors[] = 'Введите Email!';
        }
        if( $data['password'] == '')
        {   
            $errors[] = 'Введите Пароль';
        }
        if( $data['password_2'] != $data['password'] )
        {   
            $errors[] = 'Пароли не совпадают';
        }

        if( empty($errors) )
        {
            //Всё хорошо, регистрируем
        } else
        {
            echo "<div style='color: red;'>".array_shift($errors)."</div><hr>";
        }
    }
?>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<form action="/signup.php" method="POST">

    <p>
        <p><strong>Ведите ваш Никнейм</strong></p>
        <input type="text" name="nickname">
    </p>
    <p>
        <p><strong>Введите ваш E-Mail</strong></p>
        <input type="email" name="email">
    </p>
    <p>
        <p><strong>Введите ваш пароль</strong></p>
        <input type="password" name="password">
    </p>
    <p>
        <p><strong>Повторите пароль</strong></p>
        <input type="password" name="password_2">
    </p>    
    <button type="submit" name="do_signup">Создать персонажа</button>
</form>
```

Comment: echo "<div style='color: red;'>".array_shift($errors)."</div><hr>"; Вот эта строчка выводит сообщение об ошибке. Например, Я не ввёл Имя, но мне ничего не выводит

Comment: Потому что блин `$_POST` и `$_Post` это разные переменные. И ваш `if` не срабатывает __вообще__.

Comment: Хах. Точно.Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Если вы синтаксис в echo открыли с двойной кавычки то следует применять только одинарную ковычку в теле echo

```
echo "<div style='color: red;'>'.array_shift($errors).'</div><hr>";
```

либо экранируйте все двойные кавычки в теле echo

```
echo "<div style='color: red;'>\".array_shift($errors).\"</div><hr>";
```

третий вариант откройте echo с одинарной кавычкой

```
echo '<div style="color: red;">".array_shift($errors)."</div><hr>';
```

Comment: К сожалению не один вариант не выводит ошибки